# Hazelcast instance not active! in 3.3.1

Tags: hazelcast

My application is using hazelcast server with group of 3 servers. each instance on separate machine. and there is a hazelcast management center on fourth machine.

The issue I have is hazelcast inestance is not active will the backend try to get and update objects from its instance, And when I check the management center I found only two nodes instead of three nodes.
any one can help me in this?

Hazel cast version is 3.3.1.

Thanks.

Comment: if one of the your instance is not active, it is normal to see 2 instance in man center. Or i misunderstood you. Can you explain a little bit more.

Comment: Yes when the exception is occurred, there is only two active instances in in man center.

Comment: Finally I found the reason of the exception and it is crate new thread exception and this exception caused by the OS, and I solve it by increase number of threads for the user.